# cannot enter into an public aws s3 bucket which created by aws official

Tags: amazon-s3

i am trying to enter an official s3 bucket which provides some file templates, but i got access denied.
here are the s3 bucket URL and instructions i got from AWS s3 documentation:

***You can provide this information at pipeline creation and activation. The following templates available in the console are also available for download from the Amazon S3 bucket: s3://datapipeline-us-east-1/templates/***

i used this link below and try to enter
https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/datapipeline-us-east-1/templates/
but got access denied, how do i enter this kind of s3 bucket?
need help!

Comment: Did you try to access it using the AWS console or directly from your browser?

Comment: I don't know the way to access it in the AWS console. I have tried  to access it directly via the browser.

Answer (score 0):

While objects in the folder might be public, you might not be able to see the content of the folder via https.

In the command line you can browse it:

```
$ aws s3 ls "s3://datapipeline-us-east-1/templates/"
                           PRE AWS Command Line Interface (CLI) Templates/
                           PRE DynamoDB Templates/
                           PRE Elastic MapReduce (EMR) Templates/
                           PRE Getting Started/
                           PRE RDS Templates/
                           PRE Redshift Templates/
$ aws s3 ls "s3://datapipeline-us-east-1/templates/Getting Started/"
2014-11-25 15:09:41          0 
2014-11-25 15:18:39       2295 Getting Started using ShellCommandActivity.json
```

and finally, to retrieve the file you can do:

https://datapipeline-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/templates/Getting%20Started/Getting%20Started%20using%20ShellCommandActivity.json

Note the domain name difference:

- Yours:  https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
- Corrected: https://datapipeline-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com

Comment: FYI, the `aws` command requires you to install: [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)